# Regression confidence Interval: difference in SE when using Newey West method

Tags: regression, time-series, confidence-interval, hac

I would like to estimate a confidence interval for coefficients of my regression. I calculate the coefficients of the regression with the following code:

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
myRegression <- lm(x ~ y)
coeftest(myRegression, vcov = NeweyWest(myRegression, lag = NULL))
```

And the confidence interval with this code:

```
confint(Regression, vcov = NeweyWest(myRegression, lag = NULL),level = 0.95)
```

However, when I try

```
confint(Regression, level = 0.95)
```

I get the same confidence interval, although the standard error changes with the Newey West method.

Can someone explain me whether I make a mistake?

Comment: "Coefficients" is plural.  What, then, do you mean by a *single* "confidence interval" for them?  Do you mean a set of CIs?

Comment: @whuber : Or maybe an ellipsoid.

Comment: Sorry for being not precise. I have a multiple regression with several coefficients. For each one of them I would like to calculate an CI

Comment: Are you assuming i.i.d. normally distributed errors? The Newey–West method seems to be intended for use with weaker assumptions.

Comment: Its a time series analysis, I am expecting autocorrelation and heteroskedacity in the error terms - thats why I am using Newey-West...

Answer (score 1):

The `confint()` method does not allow to plug in `vcov` arguments. Therefore such the function `coefci()` has been added to `lmtest` (starting from version 0.9-35). The default `coefci(Regression)` yields the same as `confint(Regression)`. However, you can also do `coefci(Regression, vcov = NeweyWest)`. This should give what you are looking for.